# Is there any HTML element that can preserve windows CRLF, i.e \r\n

Tags: javascript, html, css

- In my program, I need to render a HTML page where user can pick specific words from the text area and use javascript to capture the selected position indexes(startIndex, endIndex) and perform further process to the source data.
- However, there's a use case the source data contains windows CRLF, when it's rendered to a text box(I used `span`), the CRLF is lost. So the index is always offset by 1 per line.
- I know potentially we can fix it from the backend, but it would be nice and more consistent if we can preserve the CRLF on the web page.

  Example code:

```js
var input = "Hello\r\nJavaScript!"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = input;
var test = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML
console.log('length of input:' + input.length)
console.log("length of test: " + test.length)
```

```css
span.demo {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="demo" id="demo">
```

I want to see `input.length==test.length`

I have explored different fashion of `white-space` style(including pre), but no luck.

The `console.log` might not be very clear for this purpose, but you can use Firefox debuger to watch the `input` variable and see `\r\n`.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Works perfectly fine, both here in the snippet, or when I copy&paste your code into a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/o1wkq92n/

Comment: The usual element is `<pre>`. Also, don't put `<span>` elements in the `<head>`; all visible content goes in `<body>`.

Comment: @04FS, it looks fine, but the `\r\n` is replaced and shorten. Please check my updated code snippet

Comment: @ChrisG, does that help answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The [`pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) element preserves newlines exactly the way you need it!

```
<pre id="test" />

<script>
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Hello\r\nJavaScript!";
</script>
```

Comment: no, it does not work. you can try dumping the length of your input string and get the length of the innerHTML afterward. It will be short by one.

Comment: I have updated my code snippet to better test it out.